# Need example for Plugin ImageEdit library in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

i searched about it about one day but i didn't find anything useful just an empty project in this link:
https://github.com/muak/Xamarin.Plugin.ImageEdit
i need an example how to load an image and add a text on it with this Library
if someone know tell me please thanks a lot.
or suggest another library with example code

Comment: https://github.com/muak/Xamarin.Plugin.ImageEdit#sample-project

Comment: @Jason thank you for comment but i already tried this sample Project its full Empty just has an empty activity...

Comment: @awrashpk The sample app is Forms based, you can reuse that NetStd2-based code in an Xamarin.Android based app.

Comment: @awrashpk If finally no useful library can be found, you also can custom a `AbsoluteLayout` with Image and Text.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT thanks for suggest but i decided to build my app with "androidHive" library in android studio. and i found out actually C# is not good for android programming at least not good as the java!

Comment: @awrashpk Yeah , C# for android is a newer to java already.There will be a long time to improve in xamarin.